# $f(x)=\frac{\sin [(2n+1)x]}{\sin x}$ is decreasing on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2n+1}]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Show that $f(x)=\dfrac{\sin [(2n+1)x]}{\sin x}$ is decreasing on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2n+1}]$. On my previous topic this problem was post for $n=1$ and I think that previuous proof can not be appliable here (in general case).

Here's my thought: $f(0)=2n+1$ and $f(\frac{\pi}{2n+1})=0$. We $$f'(x)=\dfrac{(2n+1)\cos [(2n+1)x]\sin x-\sin[(2n+1)x]\cos x}{\sin^2 x}=\dfrac{2n\cos[(2n+1)x]\sin x-\sin [2nx]}{\sin ^2x}=\dfrac{n\sin[(2n+2)x]+n\sin [2nx]-\sin [2nx]}{\sin ^2x}=$$$$=\dfrac{n\sin[(2n+2)x]+(n-1)\sin [2nx]}{\sin ^2x}=?$$
Sorry but I'm stuck here and don't know what to do next? Can anyone help me please.

Comment: Did you mean $f(x)=\dfrac{\sin[(2n+1)\color{red}{x}]}{\sin x}$? Also, by "is decreasing on $\tfrac{\pi}{2n+1}$" did you mean "is decreasing on $[0,\tfrac{\pi}{2n+1}]$" or "is decreasing at $\tfrac{\pi}{2n+1}$"?

Comment: @JimmyK4542, Thanks for remark! Edited!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [Lagrange's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Lagrange.27s_trigonometric_identities), we have 
$$f(x) = \frac{\sin (2n+1)x}{\sin x} = 1 + 2\cos 2x + 2\cos 4x + \dots + 2\cos 2nx.$$

This shows $f$ to be a sum of decreasing functions on $[0,\pi/2n]$.

Comment: Well done!  +1. - Mark